# My Javascript function is influenced by another JS function already defined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have HTML/CSS/JS page with CSS and JS functions (not created by myself) defined within the `<head>` tag. The page is displaying the title at the beginning and beneath there are four tabs defined by CSS style working dynamically using JS. Then I wanted to add my own JS function, which should be loading `onload`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function replaceSrc()
    {
        document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = "blablabla";
    }
    window.onload = replaceSrc;
</script>
```

However, when running the page, all content produced by CSS/JS disappears (just the title of the page remains).

So my questions are:

1. Can be the problem that there is already one JS function defined that is loading `onload`?
2. If so, how to handle it?

I have already tried to put the function declaration into different places within HTML, removing from   tag and putting into  tag, but still does not work.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MBvx8/. What other types of functions are there?

Comment: Could you build a fiddle reproducing the problem ? (see http://jsbin.com for example)

Comment: What's the element whose source you're changing ?

Comment: @dystroy it is <iframe> tag defined liek this: <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autohide=0"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

Answer (score 7):

When you (or somebody's else) use window.onload = someFunction, you remove all precedently attached load event handler.

You should use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) :

```
window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrc);
```

If you want to be compatible with old IE browsers, use

```
if (window.addEventListener){
  window.addEventListener('load', replaceSrc, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', replaceSrc);
}
```

---

EDIT : From your comment, it seems that you're trying to change the src of an iframe which is served by another server from another origin. You can't do this due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). See for example this related question : [Change src Iframe with cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878559/change-src-iframe-with-cross-domain)

Comment: Besides it is a good notice, it doesn't seem to be the answer for the question. Moreover, `addEventListener` is not supported by old IE.

Comment: @dystroy I have applied your code instead of window.onload = replaceSrc. My page runs perfectly now so it seems like there is no influence between different JS functions anymore, however, the function defined in the question is not working .. it does not change src attribute

Comment: I looked at the comment below your question. There's another problem, see edit in my answer.

Comment: @dystroy so what is the solution in this case? I went through the question but I didnt figure it out how to make it working. Should I refresh the src attribute and THEN change its value?

Comment: I don't think you can do it in an iframe if youtube doesn't offer a dedicated API (I never looked at that). A "solution" would be to open in another window instead of using an iframe. Or to reload your whole page each time. But it depends on YouTube HTTP headers, so you'd better look at their developer documentation or ask a very specific question on how to change iframes when the content is provided by youtube.

Comment: So using <embed> tag instead of <iframe> could be one of the ways? <object width="640" height="360">
     <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"></param>
     <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
     <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360"></embed>
  </object>

Answer (score 0):

try it using this bit of jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $("document").ready(function(){

        $("#ytplayer").attr('src', 'blablabla');

    });

</script>
```

let me know if that is what you were looking for?

or try

```
window.onload = function replaceSrc()
    {
        document.getElementById("ytplayer").src = "blablabla";
    }
```

Comment: JQuery is not a solution for my case, I have to use JavaSCript

Comment: sorry for the suggestion, i just had another look at your code and when you call the window.onload, refer to you function with the () at the end like window.onload = replaceSrc(); cheers